# Vaali and Sugriva

Tags: ramayana, advaita, rama, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I just want to know whether, when Vaali returned back to the Kingdom while Sugriva was made the King, did Sugriva apologize?

Some lectures say Sugriva apologized while some say, he apologized but still had the crown and other King's guard behind him while asking for forgiveness (this seem to have infuriated Vaali for which he drove away Sugriva).

Can someone clarify?

Comment: See yourself and get clarity :) https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga10/kishkindha_10_frame.htm

Comment: @LSSJBroly, Thank you for the link. Could you please clarify it? I am not able to understand it after going through the link.

Comment: Sugriva indeed apologized and told the truth but Vali did not believe in what he said. He said that Sugriva did it intentionally for the throne. So it was kinda misunderstanding between the two.